# SpaCy lemmatization returns 0

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

today I've tried using SpaCy lemmatization for the first time. I used Polish and English pipelines. I wrote a very simple code:

```
for token in doc:
    print(token, token.lemma)
```

I don't understand why, but what I got in return was only "Token, 0". I think I've properly loaded the language pipeline...

Answer (score 0):

`token.lemma` accesses the hash value of the tokens lemma (so an integer for its internal representation).

`token.lemma_` gives you the lemma as string so this is probably what you want.

Check out https://spacy.io/api/lemmatizer#assigned-attributes.

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that lemma has NO value at all.

Comment: I feel like that might have to do with how lemmas are handled by SpaCy, I think in most of their models it is rule-based, so there might be a special representation for unknown tokens lemmas.

Comment: And just to make it clear, I've loaded the language pipeline pl_core_media_sm and eng_core_media_sm.

Answer (score 0):

String ID 0 (an empty string) is returned if there is no information. This most likely means that the language model you're using doesn't have a pipeline component that provides lemma information.

For example, the `lemmatizer` component in [en_core_web_lg](https://spacy.io/models/en#en_core_web_lg) is what provides token lemmas in that model. Lemmas are generally set using the rule-based [Lemmatizer](https://spacy.io/api/lemmatizer) or trained [EditTreeLemmatizer](https://spacy.io/api/edittreelemmatizer) components. You can also create your own component that sets lemmas using some other method.